# HTML + CSS problems when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have made this site for a friend, and I don't know why the color of the menu bar disappears when I scroll to the right... do you have any ideas? Any help is much appreciated.

[image: problem]

The website is: www.olerisager.com

Comment: There is no color to the toolbar?

Comment: Works fine here! *Chrome

Comment: It is the dark grey menu bar that is not working properly. If the browser window is smaller than the width of the site, and you then scroll to the right, then the dark grey color of the menu bar disappears... help :-)

Comment: That's a local problem, fix your browser :P

Comment: Here is a photo of the problem http://oi59.tinypic.com/2zf2ykj.jpg

Comment: Are you sure? It seems like it is the same in all browsers..? :-)

Comment: I can reproduce her problem in Chrome

Comment: Yes when you reduce browser size and scroll to right getting issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because menu has `width: 100%` (= viewport, let's say 700px) and its children `1200px`.

Put the same width to `#menu`, or remove this wide width from children.

Comment: Cool. I'll have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the menu has a set width on it which is restricting the size of it.

Hope this helps